# Why isn't there a clear SREG RISC instruction?

Tags: assembly, avr, status-register

I was wondering why the Atmel RISC doesn't have a "clear all" instruction for the status register and only individual flag clear instructors like CLN and CLS. It is a safety thing to force the programmer to explicitly clear each bit individually and avoid carelessness?

[edit] asking because i'm examining the effect of various instructions on the status register for a class and i was looking for an instruction to reset SREG entirely when i realized such instruction doesn't exist

Comment: what does the acronym RISC mean? ... why add unnecessary instructions?

Comment: You generally care about only particular flag bits. In any case `SREG` is memory mapped so you can clear it. It's also i/o mapped. To do it with a single instruction you will need a zero register though.

Comment: What do you need such an instruction for?  The need for such an instruction is rare, definitely not common enough to spend an opcode and die space on it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question, but rather a complaint about the ISA of a particular family of devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is a safety thing to force the programmer to explicitly clear each bit individually and avoid carelessness?

No, it's just not worth providing a special instruction just for this. Note that SREG includes both the Interrupt enable/disable bit and the condition-codes, and I imagine it's pretty rare you'd ever need to clear both at once.

(Also the Transfer flag which is left unmodified even by instructions like `cmp` and `sub`, only used for `bst` / `bld` and the corresponding branches).

You don't have to run `clz` / `cln` / ... in sequence, you need at most 2 instructions.  Since this specific operation isn't common or usually useful, it's not something that most ISAs would bother to provide an instruction for.

**Covering just the condition codes** (not I and T), you can do it in 2 instructions with
**`ldi r16, 1` / `subi r16, 0`**: no Carry, no Overflow, no half-Carry, result is non-Zero, result is non-Negative.  `subi reg,0` works to clear all condition codes with any non-negative register value, so you can often avoid an extra `ldi`.

```
 cp  r16,r16       ; clears all condition codes except Z=1. (I and T unmodified)
 clz               ; Z=0
```

This 2nd way does it without modifying any other registers.  ([`andi`](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-C284B7EA-51C7-44E1-BDCD-2384F547A04F.html)/`or` leave some condition codes unset, but instructions like add/sub/compare ([`cp`](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-37152A5C-68D1-482D-9435-277B994F6220.html)) write them all.)  Any number minus itself is 0, with no carry, overflow or anything.  `cp` is like a `sub` that leaves its destination unmodified.

---

Some ISAs provide a way to copy their flags register (if they have one) to/from a general-purpose register, but AVR doesn't need to cover every corner case because its registers are memory-mapped, including SREG.  It's a RISC CPU with better uses for limited opcode space in its 16-bit fixed-width instruction format.

In [Data space](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-FAA993BC-1698-44C6-A529-249249F31012.html), SREG's address is `0x5F`.  In [I/O space](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-68D03614-A539-4991-9BD3-3D4D7B297542.html), it's `0x3F` ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR_instruction_set#Addressing)).  `out` is shorter than `sts` / `lds`, and more convenient than `st`/`ld` with an addressing mode involving an index register (X,Y, or Z).

#### To actually zero the *whole* `SREG`, including I and T, disabling interrupts

```
                     ; R1 = 0 is normally left 0 at all times, one LDI at startup
 out    $3F, r1      ; SREG = 0
```

Comment: forgive me if this is turning into a lecture, but what is the difference between:
{ldi    r16, 0;
out    $3F, r16}

and 

{ldi r16, 0;
sts $5f, R20} if they both accomplish the same thing just, only difference i've found is  'out' only requires 1 clock-cycle vs 2 cc's for 'sts'. also thanks for the answer!

Comment: @adrwstn: `sts` is a 4-byte (2-word) instruction and apparently not available on every AVR.  So like I said in my answer, shorter aka smaller (and faster).  (Deleted my first comment; your first comment was missing the code).

Comment: If the code being written follows the AVR ABI, then the ldi instruction is not necessary: register r1 will always hold the value 0 [the initialization routines in avr-libc have code that clears it]. A simple {out $3F, r16} will suffice.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Jester for pointing out that SREG is memory-mapped. I/O programming is being covered in the next class so turns out this is actually a very trivial task, hence no need reason for such instruction to exist...

```
LDI Rd, 0    ; load 0 into GPR
OUT SREG, Rd ; store register data to i/o location
```